# matplotlib contourf with extreme values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contourf

I have data I want to plot with extreme edge values, given below is a generic example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np

Z = np.random.rand(100,100)

plt.contourf(Z, 100, cmap='RdGy', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Using the above code I get this plot:
[image]

But if I change only one row of Z to contain extreme values it "dominates" the whole plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np

Z = np.random.rand(100,100)
Z[:1] *= 100

plt.contourf(Z, 100, cmap='RdGy', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

My question is so: In the second example, although I have extreme values, all the interesting things obviously happen in the range of 0 and 1, which is totally dominated by the multiplication I entered in the 1st row, even though I set vmin and vmax accordingly. How do I keep the data as is, while "focusing" on the 0-1 range? I don't really care what goes on in the first row, for all I care there can be a single color for the values 1-100.

Many Thanks.

Comment: My first solution would be to clip your data as can be shown in some comments from the link given by @Martin . But if you want to "keep the data as is", I would recommend to take a look at the `cmap` arguments and the [`Colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) class which provide a [`set_over`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_over) to define the color of the upper outliers. You should probably play with the `norm` argument too.

Comment: the set_over argument seems very relevant but I don't think it works with contourf. I tried it with pcolormesh and it works but in contourf it is just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known behavior, as reported in this [GH issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8935).

A workaround (given in the issue comments) is to use an iterable for the `levels` arguments instead of relying on `vmin` and `vmax`.

Here is a code snippet to exhibit how `vmin` and `vmax` can be used with `pcolormesh` (as you said in the comment) but how to achieve a similar result with `contourf`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np


def main():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    Z = np.random.rand(100,100)
    Z[:1] *= 100

    cmap = plt.get_cmap("viridis")

    p1 = axs[0].pcolormesh(Z, vmin=0., vmax=1, cmap=cmap)
    fig.colorbar(p1, ax=axs[0])
    p2 = axs[1].contourf(Z, levels=np.linspace(0, 1, 100), cmap=cmap)
    fig.colorbar(p2, ax=axs[1], ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: pcolormesh vs. contourf]